# Unwanted SyntaxError Exception in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I am trying harder and harder to understand why this SyntaxError exception is being thrown every time but still unable to figure out what actually triggers this exception.

Below is the code with the error thrown :

```
try:
    f = open('file.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    print(str(s))
    except OSError as err:
        print('There is some problem')
```

This is the Exception which is thrown:

```
File "<ipython-input-44-2def6d980129>", line 5
except OSError as err:
     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know this is maybe regarded as a beginner's issue, but I would rather appreciate if you a could just drop a constructive answer or a comment.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in python you have do indentation,with you have a inner value something like class to method or loop with do something inside loop
So your code must be like this :

```
try:
    f = open('name.txt')
    s = str(f.readline())
    print(s)
except OSError as err:
    print(err) #and you cant just leave this line empty because you must do something with excepted error
```

Answer (score 0):

Youyr code is not indented correctly.

Example:

```
try:
    f = open('name.txt')
    s = str(f.readline())
    print(s)
except OSError as err:
    pass
```

Comment: Okay, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation, Except should be in line with try